# Constant light intensity in render

Tags: rendering, light

I have a question about rendering. I have a simple render, object in front of direct light and camera. I have simple turnaround and I would like to have constant light intensity on the object. So far the front of the object is brighter beacause its closer to the light. How to set it up, so the object isnt in gradient of the light and shadow?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Delete your light and do light your object with your world just like that. This won't be very realistic though, might be best to use an HDRI.

Comment: Yeah, just background, looks wierd, but the HDRi background looks like something that could work.

Comment: In light setup, check the value "Custom distance" helped me